# How to do multiple-step login in IdentityServer4?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, identityserver3, identityserver4

We were using IdentityServer3, implicit grant and the login consists of multiple screen. In IdentityServer3, there's built in support for such multiple step login workflow (for example for accepting EULA, two-factor login, etc.), The feature called "*partial login*" and there is even an example: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomUserService/CustomUserService

We've recently upgraded to AspNetCore and IdentityServer4 and wondering how suppose to achieve the same? That is, check username and password in the first step, and if correct, store it securely (for example in an encrypted cookie) for the next step(s).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Our solution was to replicate the IdentityServer3's partial login: use a custom cookie to persist data between steps.

First, we need to register our custom cookie authentication (at Startup.Configure)

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "my-partial",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
    AutomaticChallenge = false
});
```

1. The first step/entry point of the login workflow should be mapped to `GET /account/login` (as of IdentityServer4 `1.0.0-rc2`).
2. In second step, after the credentials are sent and verified, we persist the username (and eventually any other data) into a cookie.

Code:

```
var claims = new []
{
    new Claim("my-user", username),
    new Claim("some-attribute", someAttribute)
};

await HttpContext.Authentication
    .SignInAsync("my-partial", new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims)));
```

**Important**: avoid using `POST /account/login` as a second step. Because regardless of your result, IdentityServer's middleware will redirect you back to the authorization endpoint (as of RC2). Just pick any other path.

3. At your last step, key parts

   - we read the persisted data from the cookie
   - remove the partial cookie
   - sign in the "real" user
   - redirect to returnUrl (this was added to the first step as a query parameter. Don't forget to send along it)

In code

```
var partialUser = await HttpContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("my-partial");
var username = partialUser?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "dr-user")?.Value;

var claims = new [] { /* Your custom claims */};

await HttpContext.Authentication
    .SignOutAsync("my-partial");

await HttpContext.Authentication
    .SignInAsync(username, username, claims);

return Redirect(returnUrl);
```

In addition, you might want to validate inputs, for example return to the first step, if there is no partial cookie, etc.

Comment: After looking at [other alternatives](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity/issues/24), we also decided to go with this (a bit altered for core 2.0), great idea! However, have you concidered this scenario?
1. User logs in with username and password and gets to step 3
2. User does not enter two factor code, but goes directly to an authorized link
3. Since the cookie is present, the user will be "Authorized" and will be able to see the protected data even though code for two-factor authentication was not entered

Comment: That can be done, but our main goal was how to securely persist data, if there are multiple steps. So basically, if you omit step 2, you don't need partial login, just set the main login: `HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(username, username, customClaims`