# Extending identityserver login flow with tenant selection page, how to get user claims on that page?

Tags: c#, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.0

I have implemented a custom AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator to include the tenant selection page to login flow based on:
[IdentityServer4 custom AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708564/identityserver4-custom-authorizeinteractionresponsegenerator)

```
public override async Task<InteractionResponse> ProcessInteractionAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request, ConsentResponse consent = null)
        {
            var response = await base.ProcessInteractionAsync(request, consent);
            if (response.IsConsent || response.IsLogin || response.IsError)
                return response;

            if (!request.Subject.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "TenantId" && c.Value != "0"))
                return new InteractionResponse
                {
                    RedirectUrl = "/Organization"
                };

            return new InteractionResponse();
        }
```

After redirecting to the /Organisation page the HttpContext does not have any information about the user or the claims since the user is not yet authenticated. How do I access user id to load the relevant tenant list for selection?

Maybe relevant: I started with the angular web app template with individual user accounts so Startup contains:

```
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddAuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator<TenantChooserResponseGenerator>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're making decision making logic using the user id claim on authentication. Why not find a way to somehow have the client relay information regarding which tenant should be used?

Comment: Because I think the way I want to do it the client doesn't need to know anything about tenants or have any logic related to tenants. Also getting the tenant id from the jwt in the api seems like a simple and secure way to set the global query filters to get tenant specific data. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Just to clarify that I understand the problem correctly, you're attempting to redirect the user to different login pages dependent on the tenant that can only be inferred with the userId right? If you want the user to be authenticated before redirecting to the tenant login I don't see how that could happen. Otherwise I'd say have a generic login page that takes in the username first, get the user id and tenant login page for that username, and redirect the user to the tenant login page from there.